# Fitting html div to screen with a scrollbar

Tags: html

I'm creating a site where the basic design consists of a few blocks on top of each other, something like this:

[image]

The first three divs are of set height and width, and the main area is also of a fixed width, with the whole thing centered horizontally on the screen. I want the main area to extend to the bottom of the screen, whatever the screen size and proportions, and to use a scroll bar within it if the contents extends beyond the bottom of the screen.

The problem I have found is that to use a scroll bar it seems you need an absolute height, so I haven't been able to find any method for fitting it and being able to scroll through the contents at the same time.

Any ideas?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried variations on setting height to 100%, setting absolute positions at the bottom of the screen, all sorts of things... I haven't recorded the specific bits of code, I'm afraid, since this project has been something I'm working on inbetween other more important jobs, so I haven't had much continuity with it.

Comment: Why not leave the default scroll behaviour alone? Set the header, bar1 and bar2 to have `position:fixed` and ensure that your main area has a `padding-top` value that allows it to clear the fixed elements.

Comment: This is how I started my answer below, the problem with this solution is that the scrollbar will go underneath the three top divs. Also, padding expands the container, unless you specify the box-sizing property, causing the body (or html, in ff) to have an additional scrollbar

Comment: If the first 3 divs are of fixed height, you can set overflow: hidden; on the body, and make the fourth div absolutely positioned with top being set at the combined height of the first 3 divs, and setting overflow: scroll on the div. This way, anything that scrolls past the height of the page will be hidden, but there will be a scroll bar in your div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this. I know there might be too many divs that are just for the look of the page, making it not 100% semantic. Anyway, here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/vSt3Z/

```
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="scroller">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.one, .two, .three {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content {
    background: yellowgreen;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-top: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;

}

.content .inner {
     height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content .inner .scroller {
    height: 1200px;
}
```

Please ignore this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

it's there just to remove an annoying default padding from jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use `calc` with `min-height`:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="first block"></div>
<div class="second block"></div>
<div class="third block"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.block{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

.first{
    background:red;
}

.second{
    background:blue;
}

.third{
    background:yellow;
}

.main{
    min-height: calc(100% - 300px);
    width:100%;
    background:green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSmJx/2/)

[caniuse calc](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: can we leave ie-8 behind already? I guess it depends on the question's owner. If he can drop ie-8, this is a valid answer. I added an extra container to have the scrollbar as in the image above: http://jsfiddle.net/VSmJx/2/

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the scroll. Updated. And yes, we can leave it behind. But if it is needed, then I would rather prefer solving it with JS rather then with CSS.

Comment: Really, I think we should avoid js if it's not really needed. Maybe having a css version and js fallback for ie 8 would make everyone happy

Comment: That is exactly what I ment :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is the simplest method:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZPU5Z/

This does not put a scroll bar on the main `#content` section only but on the whole document. Unless you have a really compelling reason to do otherwise I suggest keeping things simple (and therefore highly compatible too!).

### HTML

```
<div id="fixed-header">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="bar1">Bar 1</div>
    <div id="bar2">Bar 2</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
        Main area
</div>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: blue;
}

#fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    background-color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 50px;
}

#bar1 {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
}
#bar2 {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: green;
}

#content {
    padding-top: 100px; /* header + bar1 + bar2 */
}
```